# How to convert a Quantity to a simple Integer or Float?

Tags: units

How can I convert a quantity, such as:

```
Quantity[3, "Euros"]
```

To the simple number that represents it, in that case `3` ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `Quantity[3, "Euros"] // QuantityMagnitude`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QuantityMagnitude @ Quantity[3, "Euros"]
Information[Quantity[3, "Euros"], "Magnitude"]
Normal @ Quantity[3, "Perents"]
```

Thanks to @BobHanlon for pointing out to `QuantityMagnitude`.

From documentation of `Quantity`:

> For purely numeric units, such as percents, Normal[expr] converts a Quantity object to an ordinary number.

> Information of a Quantity may include the following properties:
> "Magnitude" - quantity magnitude, ...